# Ideal way for Nested loops in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am binding data to a Datagrid and trying to form Bands which has multiple column inside it.
I have 2 array of objects, the first one has columns and data, and the second one has band information.

```
columns= [
    {
      RNK: 1,
      MONTHS: "Jan",
      MOPS_KERO: 129.534,
      "1-2": -4532.6048,
    },
    {
      RNK: 2,
      MONTHS: "Feb",
      MOPS_KERO: 141.1474,
      "1-2": -115628.1486,
    }
  ];

bandInfo = [
    {
      SQL_COLUMN_NAME: "RNK",
      DISPLAY_COLUMN_NAME: "Rnk",
      SORT_ORDER: 1,
      BAND_NAME: "Months",
    },
    {
      SQL_COLUMN_NAME: "MONTHS",
      DISPLAY_COLUMN_NAME: "Month",
      SORT_ORDER: 2,
      BAND_NAME: "Months",
    },
    {
      SQL_COLUMN_NAME: "MOPS_KERO",
      DISPLAY_COLUMN_NAME: "Avg. Mean For Kero Fortnight Month (USC/USG)",
      SORT_ORDER: 5,
      BAND_NAME: "3",
    },
    {
      SQL_COLUMN_NAME: "1-2",
      DISPLAY_COLUMN_NAME: "Premium Achieved Over Mean (USC/USG)",
      SORT_ORDER: 6,
      BAND_NAME: "1-2",
    }
  ];
```

I am trying to achieve it through this code -

```
columns.forEach((col) => {
      this.bandInfo.forEach((element) => {
        if (col.caption == element.BAND_NAME) {
          col.columns.push({
            caption: element.DISPLAY_COLUMN_NAME,
            dataField: element.SQL_COLUMN_NAME,
          });
        } else {
          col.caption = element.BAND_NAME;
          col.columns = [];
          col.columns.push({
            caption: element.DISPLAY_COLUMN_NAME,
            dataField: element.SQL_COLUMN_NAME,
          });
        }
      });
    });
```

But with this code I am getting an output like -

```
[
  {
    "caption": "1-2",
    "dataField": "RNK",
    "columns": [
      {
        "caption": "Premium Achieved Over Mean (USC/USG)",
        "dataField": "1-2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "caption": "1-2",
    "dataField": "MONTHS",
    "columns": [
      {
        "caption": "Premium Achieved Over Mean (USC/USG)",
        "dataField": "1-2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "caption": "1-2",
    "dataField": "MOPS_KERO",
    "columns": [
      {
        "caption": "Premium Achieved Over Mean (USC/USG)",
        "dataField": "1-2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "caption": "1-2",
    "dataField": "1-2",
    "columns": [
      {
        "caption": "Premium Achieved Over Mean (USC/USG)",
        "dataField": "1-2"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

But my desired output should be like this -

```
[
  {
    "caption": "Months",
    "dataField": "RNK",
    "columns": [
      {
        "caption": "Month",
        "dataField": "MONTHS"
      },
      {
        "caption": "Rnk",
        "dataField": "RNK"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "caption": "1-2",
    "dataField": "MONTHS",
    "columns": [
      {
        "caption": "Premium Achieved Over Mean (USC/USG)",
        "dataField": "1-2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "caption": "3",
    "dataField": "MOPS_KERO",
    "columns": [
      {
        "caption": "Avg. Mean For Kero Fortnight Month (USC/USG)",
        "dataField": "MOPS_KERO"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I am getting repetitive columns with the code. I am not able to figure out what is going wrong in the nested loops.
Help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why do you need `columns` variable to produce that output. However:

```
const response = bandInfo.reduce((prev, curr) => {
    const found = prev.find((el) => el.caption === curr.BAND_NAME);
    if (!found) {
            prev.push({
            caption: curr.BAND_NAME,
            dataField: curr.SQL_COLUMN_NAME,
            columns: [
                { caption: curr.DISPLAY_COLUMN_NAME, dataField: curr.SQL_COLUMN_NAME },
            ],
        });
       return prev;
     }
     found.columns.push({
         caption: curr.DISPLAY_COLUMN_NAME,
         dataField: curr.SQL_COLUMN_NAME,
     });
     return prev;
}, []);

console.log(response)
```

Produces the output you asked for.

Comment: This helps me get the desired output!
I am using the columns variable as I am getting it from the Grid's method. That's why I was using that as an upper loop. Your answer gets the output although I was wandering if we can get it by the loops?
Thanks you!